# - (decrement) method not working as increment (+) method

Tags: scala

I am working in scala elipse in a worksheet.
Increment a += 1 method is working

But  decremnt a −= 1 method is not working.
It is giving error like 
value - not member of Int

```
object good {
var a = 1
a += 1

 a −= 1
     }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: your `−` is [Unicode Character 'MINUS SIGN' (U+2212)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2212/index.htm), which is different from ascii `-`

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Just realized while copy pasting your code. Your − (U+2212) is not normal `-` (U+002D) and that's what's breaking your code.

---

It works, as can be seen form the REPL session below:

```
scala> var a = 1
a: Int = 1

scala> a += 1

scala> a
res4: Int = 2

scala> a -= 1

scala> a
res6: Int = 1

scala>
```